# Experimental Physics - Defining convolution in terms of equipment resolution

Tags: experimental-physics, probability

So I think this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-zd-T17uiE&t=67s

By Faculty of Khan does a wonderful job in explaining what convolutions are. We basically consider two pulses $f(\tau)$ and $g(\tau)$ and "sweep" $g(t-\tau)$ from $- \infty$ to $\infty$ (We do this by taking $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$). At points $f(\tau)$ and $g(\tau)$ overlaps, the value of $(f*g)(t)$ become non-zero.

However, I would like to quote a paragraph from [KF Riley 3rd Edition](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/methodsbook.pdf)
**(page 447)**. Where the explanation of convolution is in terms of equipment resolution.

> The probability that a true reading lying between $x$ and $x+dx$, and so having probability $f(x)dx$ of being selected by the experiment, **will be moved by the instrumental resolution by an amount $z-x$ into a small interval of width $dz$ is $g(z-x)dz$**. Hence the combined probability that the interval dx will give rise to an observation appearing in the interval $dz$ is $f(x)dxg(z-x)dz$. **Adding together the contributions from all values of $x$ that can lead to an observation in the range $z$ to $z+dz$**, we find that the observed distribution is given by:
>   $$h(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(z-x)dx$$

I think this is confusing. How exactly are the bold sentences linked to the idea of two signals affecting one another (as described by the faculty of khan)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manage to work it out and I am going to answer my own question just in case someone in the future needs it.

**My answer**

[image]